# Что такое __fastcall, где он используется, зачем используется?

Tags: c++

Что такое __fastcall, где он используется, зачем используется? Стоит ли его юзать везде? Исходя из названия, скорее всего, это нужно для быстроты?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5#fastcall

Comment: Почитайте [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/fastcall?view=msvc-160) и если на какие-то вопросы (в одном вопросе xd) вы нашли ответ, то прошу конкретизировать ваш вопрос.

Comment: Подумаю над конкретизацией

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не смотря на зоопарк соглашений, на практике получили распространение всего три типа:

1. `stdcall` - стандартный вызов API-функций Win, когда аргументы передаются через стек, и после того как функция отработает, она сама снимает со-стека аргументы. Используется в архитектуре Win x86-32.
2. `cdecl` - декларация языка(С), аргументы так-же передаются через стек, но на выходе из функции мы сами должны очистить стек от аргументов (add esp,xx). Это потому, что функции `cdecl` могут иметь переменное число параметров и аргументов, и заранее неизвестно сколько им потребуется места в стеке. Яркий пример функция `printf()`.
3. `fastcall` - таким способом оформлены стандартные функции Win32API, только на системах х86-64. Здесь уже первые 4-аргумента передаются функциям через регистры RCX,RDX,R8,R9, а (если есть) 5-ый и остальные, как и прежде через стек. По этой причине вызов функций осуществляется быстрее. Очищает аргументы в стеке сама функция.

Comment: Ну вот Вам стандартное соглашение для паскаля: параметры процедур и функций передаются через стек, слева направо. Указатель на вершину стека (значение регистра esp) на исходную позицию возвращает вызываемая подпрограмма. Изменяемые параметры передаются только по ссылке. Возвращаемое значение передаётся через изменяемый параметр Result. Параметр Result создаётся неявно и является первым параметром функции.

Comment: Для сравнения stdcall: параметры функций передаются через стек, справа налево. Очистку стека производит вызываемая подпрограмма.

Comment: cdecl: параметры функций передаются через стек, справа налево. Параметры, размер которых меньше 4 байт, расширяются до 4 байт. Очистку стека производит вызывающая программа.

Answer (score 1):

`__fastcall` Соглашение о вызовах указывает, что аргументы функции должны передаваться в регистры, если это возможно. Это соглашение о вызовах применяется только к архитектуре x86.